# OnDemandGrid column sorting isn't working with dstore/Rest and Django Rest Framework

Tags: dgrid, dstore

I have created an OnDemandGrid but noticed that the column sorts weren't working on any column. The arrows are there and the screen refreshes, but it won't sort the columns in asc or desc order. I have even tried specifying for each column but it still doesn't work. Anybody having/had the same issue?

**UPDATE: 6.16.15 - After trying sortParam suggestion:**
Comment below explains. It appears to be doing the right thing... but still won't sort.

[image]

**UPDATE 6.16.15 - 4:00pm** 
Apparently ANY type of filtering or sort doesn't work well with Django - trying to determine how set filtering where dojo can communicate to Django Rest or vice versa - so far haven't been able to find a setting on either side that works. Not only does column sort not work - creating a search field doesn't work, nor creating a sort button.

[image]

This is after changing to the ORDERING_PARAM in DJANGO settings.py to 'SORT'... for all intensive purposes this looks like it should work.

Comment: If you're using a server-based store, this is most likely because your service doesn't understand the sort parameter that the client-side store implementation is sending...  Are you on 0.3 with dojo/store or 0.4 with dstore at this point?

Comment: dojo 1.10 - dstore - dgrid 0.4 -server based store is the Django Rest Framework, which pulls from a MySQL database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search through the [Django Rest Framework documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#orderingfilter) reveals that it defaults to expecting an `ordering` query parameter to indicate which field should be sorted.  The `dstore/Request` store (inherited by `Rest`) allows you to indicate the query parameter name that sends sort information, via `sortParam`.

Additionally, it appears that DRF's OrderingFilter indicates ascending sort with no prefix, and descending sort with `-`.  `dstore/Request` defaults to expecting `+` and `-` as prefixes, but these can be overridden via `ascendingPrefix` and `descendingPrefix`.

So in your case, you'll want to include `sortParam: 'ordering', ascendingPrefix: ''` in the properties passed when you create your `Rest` store instance.

In general, when you run into store-related issues like this where the grid and backend don't seem to be making ends meet, this is the process you'll have to follow - find out what the server expects, find out what the client-side store implements, and see if it can be tweaked or needs to be customized.

UPDATE 6.17.15 - 
Changing server side settings to match dojo/dgrid parameters -

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': ('rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser',),
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination',
 #   'PAGE_SIZE': 25,
    'ORDERING_PARAM': 'sort'
```

Comment: I have added the sortParam - still not working properly... in firebug it gives the appearance it's working properly though... still trying to troubleshoot.

Comment: I found something in the Django Rest Documentation where you can set the ordering preference to Sort in settings.py and it works (at least from firebug's perspective anyway)- however, it STILL won't sort... any ideas?? This doesn't make sense that it won't work either way.

Comment: It still comes down to what the client sends vs. what the server receives...  Look at the query string of the requests `dstore/Rest` is sending, and double-check the documentation as to what the server actually expects.  Since you seem to be using Firefox, an extension like [REST Easy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/rest-easy/) might help to test things out.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed you updated the original question.  It looks like you are still not setting `sortParam` or `ascendingPrefix` on the store as I suggested, given the `&sort(+id)` example (which would become `&ordering=id`)

Comment: I did try that earlier... and it did switch it to ordering. When that didn't work either, I switched it at the server side to do sort instead of ordering... that was the most recent change I did. The picture above the most recent shows the ordering=id. Neither one is working properly.

Comment: Can you provide more information on what you attempted to configure on the server?  It's impossible to guess what combination of things is/isn't working at this point.

Comment: In Django Rest there is an ORDERING_PARAM setting that you can override the "ordering" default. I added this to the settings.py and changed the default to "sort". Before that I tried what you had suggested. I updated the question to show the settings.py for DRF.

Comment: Okay, even if you change that to `sort` I believe you are still going to need to set `sortParam: 'sort'` on your dstore instance to change the query from `sort(...)` to `sort=...`, and you will likely still need to set `ascendingPrefix: ''` as well since I'm guessing DRF still doesn't expect a `+` to indicate ascending sort.

Comment: Thank you! I just tried that as well. Still not working unfortunately. :( I'll keep digging around in the docs to see if I can figure it out. Thanks for hanging with me this long!!